# variables in zend framework bootstrap

Tags: zend-framework

I have $view variables in two function in bootstrap file they don't work at the same time unless i comment out one of them, i need to use both function please help

```
protected function _initNavigation()
{
    $this->bootstrap('layout');
    $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
   // $view = $layout->getView();
   // $navigation = new Zend_Navigation($this->getOption('navigation'));
   // $view->navigation($navigation);
}

protected function _initjQuery(){
    $view = new Zend_View();
    $view->addHelperPath("ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper", "ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper");
    $viewRenderer = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer();
    $viewRenderer->setView($view);
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In one function you're using the View object from the layout resource, and in the other you're creating a new View object. If you change your second function to work like the first you don't need to create a new View or inject it into the view renderer.

I'd suggest changing your code to this:

```
protected function _initNavigation()
{
    $this->bootstrap('layout');
    $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
    $view = $layout->getView();
    $navigation = new Zend_Navigation($this->getOption('navigation'));
    $view->navigation($navigation);
}

protected function _initjQuery()
{
    $this->bootstrap('layout');
    $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
    $view = $layout->getView();
    $view->addHelperPath("ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper", "ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper");
}
```